# How to enable device option to connect to external device on android studio?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to connect my android device to android studio to run flutter but keep having this issue:
The result should be like this:
[image]

But instead, I can't open the device option on my android studio:
[image]

When I run flutter doctor there is no error and the device I plug in show up.
The machine I'm using is Asus TUF A15 which runs AMD Ryzen 5 4600H processor.

Can anyone please show me the way to enable this option?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable developer options and USB debugging on your android device. More information can be found on the Android documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options).
2. Plug your phone into your computer with a USB cable. Allow your computer to access your device if prompted.
3. In your terminal, run `flutter devices` to verify that Flutter recognizes your devices
4. Run `flutter run` to start your Flutter app or use the function available in Android Studio.
5. You should also try another USB cable, another Android device, or even another USB port on your computer. (Something simple, but can easily get overlooked)